# Using custom templates with Hibernate tools reverse engineering from Gradle

Tags: hibernate, templates

Using the Hibernate ant task from with Gradle I'm able to generate entity classes from a database using the documentation at http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#d0e5102

When I change `template` and `templateprefix`, Hibernate cannot find my custom templates.  To be sure, I copied the templates directly from the hibernate jars and added a single comment to the Pojo.ftl.

Here's my working Gradle build file with the Hibernate templates... below the working build file is the failing one, which is identical except for the `template` and `templateprefix`.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    reverseMap
}

dependencies {
    reverseMap 'org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:4.0.0-CR1'
    reverseMap 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5'
    reverseMap files('/Users/jzwolak/local/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar')
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}

project.ext {
    hibernateRevEngXml = "$projectDir/config/hibernate.reveng.xml"
    hibernateDestDir = file("$buildDir/generated")
}

task reverseMap {
    inputs.files hibernateRevEngXml
    outputs.dir hibernateDestDir
    doLast {
        hibernateDestDir.exists() || hibernateDestDir.mkdirs()
        ant {
            taskdef(name: 'hibernatetool',
                    classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
                    classpath: configurations.reverseMap.asPath )
            hibernatetool( destdir : hibernateDestDir ) {
                jdbcconfiguration(
                        configurationfile:"$projectDir/config/hibernate.cfg.xml",
                        revengfile:hibernateRevEngXml,
                        packagename:
                                "com.mybiz"
                        //reversestrategy="ReverseEngineeringStrategy classname"
                        //detectmanytomany="true|false"
                        //detectoptmisticlock="true|false"
                )
                hbmtemplate(
                    templateprefix:"pojo/" ,
                    template:"pojo/Pojo.ftl", 
                    filepattern:"{package-name}/{class-name}.java"
                ) {
                    property(key:"jdk5",value:"true")
                    property(key:"ejb3",value:"true")
                }
                /*
                hbm2java(
                        jdk5: true,
                        ejb3: true
                )
                */
                // Adds the config directory to the path so that log4j can pick up
                // its properties file.
                classpath {
                    pathelement( path: "config" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava.source reverseMap.outputs.files, sourceSets.main.java
```

And here's the failing build file.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    reverseMap
}

dependencies {
    reverseMap 'org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:4.0.0-CR1'
    reverseMap 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.5'
    reverseMap files('/Users/jzwolak/local/lib/ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar')
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
}

project.ext {
    hibernateRevEngXml = "$projectDir/config/hibernate.reveng.xml"
    hibernateDestDir = file("$buildDir/generated")
}

task reverseMap {
    inputs.files hibernateRevEngXml
    outputs.dir hibernateDestDir
    doLast {
        hibernateDestDir.exists() || hibernateDestDir.mkdirs()
        ant {
            taskdef(name: 'hibernatetool',
                    classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
                    classpath: configurations.reverseMap.asPath )
            hibernatetool( destdir : hibernateDestDir ) {
                jdbcconfiguration(
                        configurationfile:"$projectDir/config/hibernate.cfg.xml",
                        revengfile:hibernateRevEngXml,
                        packagename:
                                "com.mybiz"
                        //reversestrategy="ReverseEngineeringStrategy classname"
                        //detectmanytomany="true|false"
                        //detectoptmisticlock="true|false"
                )
                hbmtemplate(
                    templateprefix:"templates/custom_pojo/" ,
                    template:"templates/custom_pojo/Pojo.ftl", 
                    filepattern:"{package-name}/{class-name}.java"
                ) {
                    property(key:"jdk5",value:"true")
                    property(key:"ejb3",value:"true")
                }
                /*
                hbm2java(
                        jdk5: true,
                        ejb3: true
                )
                */
                // Adds the config directory to the path so that log4j can pick up
                // its properties file.
                classpath {
                    pathelement( path: "config" )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

compileJava.source reverseMap.outputs.files, sourceSets.main.java
```

And here's the directory tree

```
build.gradle
config
|    hibernate.cfg.xml
|    hibernate.reveng.xml
|    log4j.properties
templates
|    custom_pojo
|    |    Ejb3PropertyGetAnnotation.ftl
|    |    Ejb3TypeDeclaration.ftl
|    |    GetPropertyAnnotation.ftl
|    |    Pojo.ftl
|    |    PojoConstructors.ftl
|    |    PojoEqualsHashcode.ftl
|    |    PojoExtraClassCode.ftl
|    |    PojoFields.ftl
|    |    PojoInterfacePropertyAccessors.ftl
|    |    PojoPropertyAccessors.ftl
|    |    PojoToString.ftl
|    |    PojoTypeDeclaration.ftl
|    |    test.ftl
```

Here's the error

```
[ant:hibernatetool] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ExporterException: Error while processing Entity: com.mybiz.TsModelRealizationView with template templates/custom_pojo/Pojo.ftl
[ant:hibernatetool] java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template templates/custom_pojo/Pojo.ftl not found.
:reverseMap FAILED
```

I've tried adding `.` and `templates` to the classpath along with `config`, which is already in the classpath and working.

I've tried numerous combinations for `template` and `templateprefix`, but the only ones that work are the ones in the first build.gradle file above.

**UPDATE**

I tried with absolute paths for `templateprefix` and `template` and got the same file not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
reverseMap files('.')
```

to your dependencies.

Comment: Why ? What is this ? I'm getting the same error when generating annotated code from hbm.xml files, and I don't have any build.xml...

Answer (score 0):

Little late but if it still helps, this is the other way to specify the base path of templates:

Change this:

```
hibernatetool( destdir : hibernateDestDir )
```

to:

```
hibernatetool( destdir : hibernateDestDir, templatepath : 'templates' )
```

and templates part should be:

```
templateprefix:"custom_pojo/" ,
template:"custom_pojo/Pojo.ftl",
```