# How can I use the latest version of Hibernate Tools with Gradle to reverse engineer persistence objects from the database?

Tags: java, spring, gradle, hibernate-tools

Following along with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66135295/hibernate-tools-reverse-engineering-with-gradle), I was able to use Gradle to reverse engineer Java entities from a MySQL 8 database.

However, the highest version of **hibernate-tools** and **hibernate-core** that worked without error is **4.3.5.Final**.

When updating my build.gradle to use a newer version of **hibernte-tools** and **hibernate-core** (e.g. **5.6.2.Final** or newer), I get this error:

```
 Task :reverseMap FAILED
HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProviderImpl.java:44)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173)
        at org.hibernate.tool.internal.metadata.JdbcMetadataDescriptor.getMetadataCollector(JdbcMetadataDescriptor.java:92)
        at org.hibernate.tool.internal.metadata.JdbcMetadataDescriptor.createMetadata(JdbcMetadataDescriptor.java:65)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.buildMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.getMetadata(AbstractExporter.java:56)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.setupContext(AbstractExporter.java:177)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.POJOExporter.setupContext(POJOExporter.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.AbstractExporter.start(AbstractExporter.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.tool.ant.ExporterTask.execute(ExporterTask.java:39)
        at org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:174)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:299)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:99)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:335)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:280)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:90)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:160)
        at groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:215)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(BasicAntBuilder.java:117)
        at groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$GroovyObjectAdapter.invokeOpaqueMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:584)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:511)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:408)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:348)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:61)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
        at build_5jkow12rms5eudzcotor2w7gj$_run_closure6$_closure8$_closure9.doCall(/Users/samuel04/Dev/projects/Consultant-Dashboard/build.gradle:70)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:274)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configureTarget(ConfigureUtil.java:155)
        at org.gradle.util.internal.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:106)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.ant(DefaultProject.java:1189)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor688.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:484)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.BeanDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:196)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.CompositeDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.extensibility.MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(MixInClosurePropertiesAsMethodsDynamicObject.java:34)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript$ScriptDynamicObject.tryInvokeMethod(BasicScript.java:135)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.ConfigureDelegate.invokeMethod(ConfigureDelegate.java:77)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:408)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:348)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:819)
        at groovy.lang.GroovyObject.invokeMethod(GroovyObject.java:39)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeOnDelegationObjects(ClosureMetaClass.java:424)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:350)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:61)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
        at build_5jkow12rms5eudzcotor2w7gj$_run_closure6$_closure8.doCall(/Users/samuel04/Dev/projects/Consultant-Dashboard/build.gradle:64)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:274)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1035)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.doExecute(AbstractTask.java:751)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.lambda$execute$0(AbstractTask.java:738)
        at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:98)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:738)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:713)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$3.run(TaskExecution.java:242)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeAction(TaskExecution.java:227)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeActions(TaskExecution.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(TaskExecution.java:193)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution.execute(TaskExecution.java:171)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeInternal(ExecuteStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:74)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:55)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:29)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:42)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:60)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:180)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.lambda$execute$1(BuildCacheStep.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.Either$Right.fold(Either.java:175)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.caching.CachingState.fold(CachingState.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:25)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:110)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:114)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:50)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.executeWithNoEmptySources(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:249)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:86)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.execute(RemoveUntrackedExecutionStateStep.java:21)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadPreviousExecutionStateStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.TaskExecution$4.withWorkspace(TaskExecution.java:287)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:30)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:27)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine$1.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:76)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:144)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:133)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:333)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:320)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:313)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:299)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:143)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:227)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:218)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:140)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
[ant:hibernatetool] An exception occurred while running exporter #2:hbm2java (Generates a set of .java files)
[ant:hibernatetool] To get the full stack trace run ant with -verbose
[ant:hibernatetool] org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
[ant:hibernatetool] org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

This is my **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
  id 'java'                                     // Java for Java application tasks
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.3' // Spring Boot for quickly making applications with the Java Spring Framework
}

// The 'repositories' method specifies sources for Gradle to look at for application dependencies
repositories {
  mavenCentral() // Consult the Apache Maven software registry/build depot for dependencies
}

group = 'com.test.app' // Uniquely identifies the project (should follow the Java package name rules)
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'                           // The version of the project Gradle is building
sourceCompatibility = '17'                           // Java source language level
targetCompatibility = '17'                           // Java ByteCode language level

configurations {
  reverseMap
}

// The 'dependencies' method specifies the actual application dependencies and their types
dependencies {
  implementation(project(':src:main:ui'))                                        // This project uses the "ui" project
  annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'                         // Project Lombok is a lodash-like utility package for Java Spring applications
  compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'                                 // Project Lombok is a lodash-like utility package for Java Spring applications
  runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'                                // JDBC Type 4 driver for MySQL database connections to Java applications
  testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'                 // JUnit Jupiter Engine for Java unit testing
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.6.4'   // Spring Boot Starter Data JPA for using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.6.4' // Spring Boot Starter Validation for using Java Bean validation with Hibernate Validator
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.6.4'        // Spring Boot Starter Web for building web applications (using Spring MVC)
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.6.4'   // Spring Boot Starter Test for testing Spring Boot applications with JUnit Jupiter
  testImplementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.1.0'               // WebDriverManager
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'                 // JUnit Jupiter API for development
  testImplementation 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.22.0'                           // AssertJ Fluent Assertions for Java unit testing
  reverseMap 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.2.Final'
  reverseMap 'org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:5.6.2.Final'
  reverseMap 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.36'
  reverseMap 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.28'
}

tasks.test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

project.ext {
  hibernateDestDir = file("$projectDir/src/main/java")
}

task reverseMap {
  outputs.dir hibernateDestDir
  doLast {
    hibernateDestDir.exists() || hibernateDestDir.mkdirs()
    ant {
      taskdef(
              name: 'hibernatetool',
              classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask',
              classpath: configurations.reverseMap.asPath
      )
      hibernatetool(destdir: hibernateDestDir) {
        jdbcconfiguration(
                configurationfile: "$projectDir/provision/reverse-engineering/hibernate.cfg.xml",
                packagename: "com.test.app.persistence"
        )
        hbm2java(
                jdk5: true,
                ejb3: true
        )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my **hibernate.cfg.xml** file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            dbuser
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            dbpass
        </property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Something has changed between version 4.x.x and 5.x.x of Hibernate Tools and Hibernate Core. Has anyone else encountered this in a Gradle build? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: Judging from the error your cfg file isn't loaded. As it complains about the dialect and connection. Enable debug logging to see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem and can now run the hibernatetool task using hibernate-tools 5.6.2.FINAL. I made the following changes:

1. Add the following files to /src/main/resources:

**hibernate.properties**

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db
hibernate.connection.username=dbuser
hibernate.connection.password=dbpass
```

**hibernate.reveng.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering SYSTEM "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
  
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>  
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

2. Modify the **hibernatetool** block in **build.gradle** by setting the *propertyFile* property instead of the *configurationFile* property, and also set the *revengFile* property:

   ```
   hibernatetool(destdir: hibernateDestDir) {
       jdbcconfiguration(
           propertyFile: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/hibernate.properties",
           revengFile: "$projectDir/src/main/resources/hibernate.reveng.xml",
           packagename: "com.test.app.persistence",
           reversestrategy: "com.test.app.persistence.hibernate.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy"
       )
       hbm2java(jdk5: true, ejb3: true)
   }
   ```
3. Deleted the **hibernate.cfg.xml** file, as its no longer necessary.

Now when I run the **reverseMap** gradle task, I get this:

```
HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```